# Using GDAL command line to copy projections

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, imagej

I have two images, a georeferenced Tiff and a second Tiff without a reference. The second image is a copy of the first, but it lost its reference. Now, I want to copy the reference from the first Tiff to the second Tiff using GDAL using the command line.

I had a look at several gdal utilities like gdalwarp, gdal_translate etc. but it seems that they only work on one image at a time and cannot "copy" a projection.

How can I do this?

I am using ImageJ for image analysis (segmentation) on 600 Tiff-images, all formerly geotiffs. However, during import ImageJ sets the xmin,ymin to (0,0) and looses all spatial information. Now, I try to use GDAL within an ImageJ macro to reload the spatial information so that the segmentation output also has a proper spatial reference

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would recommend to use [gdalcopyproj.py](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdalcopyproj.py), a sample file from the GDAL repository done for this purpose as mentioned directly in the script:

> Duplicate the geotransform and projection metadata from
> one raster dataset to another, which can be useful after
> performing image manipulations with other software that
> ignores or discards georeferencing metadata.

The command line is just:

```
gdalcopyproj.py source_file dest_file
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that this would be the best way, however I am too stupid to setup python/gdal on windows 7. I have the OSGEO4W installed (with GDAL 1.11.0), yet I failed to get the python bindings running. I ended up with downloading GDAL, and then SWIG, which I could not get running, neither the python command examples...any suggestions where to start?

Comment: NB this does not seem change the original `dest_file` but stores the srs information in an XML file. At least that was the case for a set of jp2 files.

Answer (score 5):

Use gdalsrsinfo to get the srs of the tiff that still has the projection:

```
gdalsrsinfo -o wkt tiffwithsrs.tiff
```

Then copy the output and use gdal_translate to apply it to a new tiff:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs '...' tiffwithoutsrs.tif newfixedtif.tif
```

just paste your projection after the -a_srs option

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea, however, I just realized that I also need the extent from the former image, not just the projection. -o wkt only gets the projection (what I asked for, I know...)

Comment: Ah.  You can use gdal_edit.py to edit corners and srs.  It just overwrites data:

http://gdal.org/gdal_edit.html

Comment: I did what user10353 suggests, but the command copied the whole .tif file and not only the georeferencing....

Answer (score 2):

I would use listgeo http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html and then geotifcp.

Comment: +1 but note that not all versions of listgeo/geotifcp support tiffs > 4GB (i.e "bigtiffs").

Comment: Great, that worked. It took me a while to figure out HOW it works. It is a two step process. First dump the projection info into a text file, then use geotifcp to glue that header onto the "headerless" tif-file. And all info is used. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me, and I found this answer that explained the usage of these utilities https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48383