# Intersection between shapefiles using gdal

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogr

From three *.tif* files I got the relative associated *.shp* files through gdaltindex.
Now, I'd like to create a new *.shp* file given by the intersection of the three *shp.* files previously obtained.
How could I do this through gdal?

I found this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234512/matching-two-rasters-with-different-projections-and-resolution)
but I don't know how to create OGR VRT layer.

Comment: Info here: https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet

Comment: thank you very much, it was very helpful.
I think I solved it like this:
ogr2ogr -clipsrc master.shp output.shp slave.shp

In my case (3 .shp files)
ogr2ogr -clipsrc master.shp output.shp slave_one.shp
ogr2ogr -clipsrc output.shp output_finale.shp slave_two.shp