# Georeferencing multiple images as GeoTIFF (same size and extents) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, image, world-file

I have 50 images and I want to georeference them all on to the exactly same place. They have all the exactly same size and extends. I've begun to load the same georeferencing points for every single image and georeferenced it... but this takes a way too long.

Is there a easy way to georeference them with one coordinate file as batch all to the same place?

Comment: Ive added to every ungeoreferenced tif the worldfile from the first georeferenced tif. Batch renamed the worldfiles, that they have the same name as the images. It works. But I need Geotiff instead of tiff with a worldfile. Is there a option in qgis to batch saving multiple georeferenced tiff layer to geotiff ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use GDAL command line to copy projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108673/use-gdal-command-line-to-copy-projections)